# components above react-native-tabs-section-list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

I'm using this library https://github.com/bogoslavskiy/react-native-tabs-section-list

I want to put the components in the same screen above that tabs-section-list component when I pass property `ListHeaderComponent={aboveMyListComps}`

The component `aboveMyListComps` is being placed between the tabs and the section list.

I have already tried wrapping the whole screen inside a scroll view as a result either my tabs header scroll away from the screen, or when I try to use `stickyHeaderIndices` property of the tabs-section-list doesn't scroll.

[example of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wweQa.jpg)

In this example I want my text 'TEST' to be above the header tabs list